# Compare value of QueryString with value from Repeater's DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, repeater

I have a `<asp:Repeater>` and I need to show/hide a button inside it depending on the value of a specific field from it's `DataSource`. As you can see in the code below, I'm trying to compare `Eval("ProcessId") == Request.QueryString["ProcessId"]`. Is it possible? What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to compare this value to, let's say, a `Control` (like a `TextBox`) on the page?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonDelete" Visible="<% Eval("ProcessId") == Request.QueryString["ProcessId"] ? 'false' : 'true' %>" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UniqueId") %>' Text="Delete" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you cast `Request.QueryString` to `string`

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonDelete" 
Visible='<%# Eval("ProcessId") == (string)Request.QueryString["ProcessId"] ? false : true %>' CommandName="Delete" />
```